# Opening a notebook from command line in an existing front end instance

Tags: front-end, linux

I am using Linux, and I would like to be able to programmatically open notebooks in a running Mathematica instance from the command line.  Currently, doing something like

/opt/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/Executables/Mathematica foo.nb

launches a new kernel/frontend instance.  Is it possible to re-use a running frontend for opening notebooks (short of enforcing single-instance behavior, for which I believe there is a command line option)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can start Mathematica with :

```
/opt/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/Executables/Mathematica -sl &
```

and then open your notebook in the same session with :

```
/opt/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/Executables/Mathematica -sl foo.nb
```

From the man page `Mathematica --help` :

> -sl (--singlelaunch): Open in an existing process, if possible.

Comment: Yes, the `-sl` flag does the trick. Another instance of Mathematica can still be launched by omitting the flag; opening notebooks afterwards with the `-sl` flag will still be bringing them up in the first instance

Comment: It seems it's very important that the first instance is also started with `-sl`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to change the shortcut so this is the default always

Comment: Its `/usr/local/bin/Mathematica -sl` in my version of ubuntu but yes it works.

Comment: @William, did you find a convenient way to make this the default. (I open files by double-clicking and don't want to have to have to use the command line). (I would also be very happy creating many instances if not for the fact that Mathematica only allows me to open two instances probably for some crazy license reason).

Comment: @Kvothe I no longer have Mathematica installed currently.  It may make sense to ask another question considering this is only for the command line.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273776/opening-a-notebook-in-an-existing-instance-by-double-clicking-the-file-linux for how to set this as the default way to open mathematica files using the file explorer.