# Sending a command to an already opened frontend

Tags: notebooks, scripting

I'm trying to pipe low-level notebook commands to work through terminal and I've tried various ways, but I can't really get to the frontend that's already open.
For example [Opening a notebook from command line in an existing front end instance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/opening-a-notebook-from-command-line-in-an-existing-front-end-instance) this no longer works.

I've tried connecting to notebooks kernel, but it didn't work as I expected... perhaps I know too little.

I'd imagine it to work like this:

math -script file.m
or 
mathematica file.m

Where file.m would contain commands to evaluate on currently opened notebooks in an existing mathematica instance.
How should I approach it?