# How to open notebooks in already running instances of the Front End on Linux?

Tags: front-end, linux

On Windows and OS X, if Mathematica is already running, double clicking a notebook doesn't open a new Front End instance.  Instead it will conveniently open the notebook in the already running instance.

How can I achieve the same behaviour on Linux?

Running

```
mathematica mynotebook.nb
```

from the command line always opens a completely new instance of the Front End on Linux, even if another Front End was already running.  I believe graphical file managers simply run this command when double clicking a notebook.

Comment: Mine always opens directly; I forget if I had to change one of the settings for this to take place, though.

Comment: Mine opens directly as well, using Mathematica 10.0.2.0 under Windows 8.1 (64x).  I am confident that I have not changed settings to accomplish this.

Comment: Also opens directly, using Mathematica 9.0.1.0 under Windows 8.1 (64x).

Comment: Very embarrassingly for me, I just realized that this was a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/opening-a-notebook-from-command-line-in-an-existing-front-end-instance

Comment: @Szabolcs Bounty returned; go apply it to the original.

Answer (score 1):

In the lower left corner of the welcome screen, there is a checkbox labeled "Show at startup". Uncheck it to bypass the welcome screen.

Alternatively, bring up the Options Inspector (Format > Options Inspector...) and search for "ShowAtStartup".  Make sure the pull down menu in the upper left reads "Global Preferences" and choose "NewDocument" for the value of "ShowAtStartup".

Comment: But, notebooks open for me by double-clicking, and I do not need to do this.  Also, "ShowAtStartup" is set to "Welcome".  Perhaps, the behavior in question depends on the version of Mathematica

Comment: It opens a new document instead of opening the file on which I am double-clicking.

Comment: As I understand, the OP has two problems: 1. double clicking a notebook open a completely new instance of the Mathematcia front end instead of opening the notebook in the existing one  2. he says that the notebook isn't even opened in the new instance.  I have problem 1 but not problem 2.  Unchecking "Show at startup" will not fix problem 1, just hide it.  The underlying problem is that it can't figure out that a different front end is already running ...

Comment: I thought I'd edit the OP's question to clarify this a bit (instead of asking a completely new question).  That might make your answer look a bit out of place ... apologies in advance for this.

Comment: @Szabolcs It won't be the first time I've looked awkward.