# Opening a notebook in an existing instance by double clicking the file (Linux)

Tags: front-end, linux

Is it possible to change a setting or something in order to open files in existing Mathematica instances instead of in a new instances when double clicking the file. (This is convenient since Mathematica limits the number of instances that are allowed to open based on the license.)

Using the command line a solution was proposed in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13610/45020 however that question does not go into how to achieve the same thing in through a file explorer through double clicking / open with.

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74173/how-to-open-notebooks-in-already-running-instances-of-the-front-end-on-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1) is similar but was considered a duplicate of the question in the first link because it didn't emphasize  that it was looking for a graphical interface solution and not a command line one.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with Nemo 4.42 as my file explorer.

Answer (score 5):

I created a script `MathematicaSingleInstance` in `/usr/local/bin` that refers to `/usr/local/bin/Mathematica` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

Mathematica -sl "$@"
```

After making the file executable (see Properties/Permissions), Mathematica files can be set to be opened using `MathematicaSingleInstance` by default and this indeed opens all Mathematica files in the first opened instance.

Answer (score 2):

Under Gnome (I use Pop OS), I just added the `-sl` flag to the Exec line in `/usr/share/applications/wolfram-mathematica13.desktop` and it seems to work well:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Mathematica 13
Comment=Technical Computing System
TryExec=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.1/Executables/Mathematica
Exec=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.1/Executables/Mathematica -sl --name M-13.1 %F
Icon=wolfram-mathematica
StartupWMClass=M-13.1
MimeType=application/mathematica;application/x-mathematica;application/vnd.wolfram.nb;application/vnd.wolfram.cdf;application/vnd.wolfram.player;application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica.package;application/vnd.wolfram.wl;x-scheme-handler/wolfram+cloudobject;x-scheme-handler/wolframmathematica+cloudobject;
```

*UPDATE*: For some reason, this stopped working for me as described above. The solution I found is to save the .desktop file to this location instead: `~/.local/share/applications/`. This is better as the file can be kept with your local user permissions making is easier to update for new Mathematica releases.