# Shared variables between notebooks using the same kernel not working in mathematica 10.1?

Tags: kernel, system, system-variables, user-interface

I am trying to access the variables over two Mathematica documents, this works fine when I use Mathematica 9 but when I attempt to do the same on 10.1 it doesn't work.

I have set both notebooks to have global context and to operate on the same kernel. I am not sure how to resolve this issue, is it a new feature of 10.1?

(Quick Update: Seems to be opening two different instances of mathematica, i.e. I can close the kernel in one but not affect the kernel of the other even though both are set to local.)

Comment: What is your OS?  Is it Linux?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/opening-a-notebook-from-command-line-in-an-existing-front-end-instance