# keyboard shortcut to invoke Insert new matrix

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I frequently need to type in some matrices, and the menu command `Insert`>`Table/Matrix`>`New...` allows matrices with lines drawn between columns and rows, which is very helpful. I would like to make a keyboard shortcut for it, but cannot find the relevant frontend token command [(4209405)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts) for it. Since the `FullForm[]` and `InputForm[]` of matrices with lines drawn between rows and columns is the same as those without lines, it's hard to do this via 3rd party system-wide text expanders (e.g. autohotkey or atext on mac). How does one assign a keyboard shortcut for the menu item `Insert`>`Table/Matrix`>`New...`, preferably using only mathematica? Thanks!

Comment: If you just use the keyboard shortcut for `Add Row` or `Add Column` it will create a new matrix, but not pull up the dialog box. **edit** I see that isn't what you are looking for

Comment: @JasonB Yes, I'm aware of that. I can programmatically do the fill all and fill diagonal function in the dialogue box, but the lines between the rows and columns are really nice for my needs and I can not reproduce that without clicking the menu item.

Comment: The token seems to be "CreateGridBoxDialog"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `MenuSetup.tr` (for linux located in the $InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/ directory), I changed the line

> MenuItem["&New...", "CreateGridBoxDialog"]

to read

> MenuItem["&New...", "CreateGridBoxDialog", MenuKey["m", Modifiers->{"Control"}]]

and now I have the keyboard shortcut

[image]

<s>But maybe it is safer to change the  `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file, since now that I've done this I can't get the [singlelaunch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13602/9490) option to work any more</s> - fixed via restart.

Comment: thanks! and sorry for the singlelaunch trouble

Comment: It fixed via a restart so no worries.  That is a real pain for linux, if you don't use that every time you double click a notebook it opens a new instance of Mathematica.