# Is every menu command equivalent to a command that can be executed within a notebook?

Tags: kernel-startup, menu

If so, is there a directory which gives the in-notebook command associated with each menu command ?

In particular, I would like to know how to replicate the menu command Evaluation -> Quit Kernel -> Local.

It doesn't seem to behave the same way as CloseKernels[], nor as AbortKernels[]. I can demonstrate this if required.

Comment: `Exit[]`?$\phantom{}$

Comment: To execute front end commands from the kernel have a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FrontEndTokens.html)

Comment: related: [76484](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76484/5478), ["MenuCommand"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MenuCommand), [What is the complete list of valid Front End Tokens?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2572/5478).

Comment: At the end you can investigate [MenuSetup.tr](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105487/5478) where some of tokens can be linked to MenuItems.