# Ubuntu Opens New Session

Tags: linux

[So after reading this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/opening-a-notebook-from-command-line-in-an-existing-front-end-instance) it appears Mathematica can resume sessions essentially if you pass it the -sl option.

Is there a way to make it act more like Windows and OSX and make this the default when clicking on the Mathematica icon in the dock?

Comment: I think all you need to do is right-click on the icon that you use to open MMA, click "Edit", and add the `-sl` option to the command there.  Don't have Linux at the moment so I can't test, but I think that's how I had mine set up.

Comment: @JasonB there is no edit option on my version of Ubuntu.  I believe it has to do with the .desktop files

Comment: Right on, I didn't use Unity at the time.  So you need to find the appropriate `.desktop` file and edit it to add the option there.  This should be relevant  http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't particularly difficult once you find the appropriate file.
Edit the following file `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/wolfram-mathematica10.desktop`

and modify the corresponding file to the following.

```
Exec=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/Executables/Mathematica -sl %F
```