# Using an existing local kernel when launching from command line

Tags: scripting, command-line

I am trying to setup a web interface to a couple of Mathematica scripts, which in itself is quite simple:

```
<?php
$script = "myScript.wls";
echo shell_exec('wolframscript -print all -format List -file '.$script);
```

However, how can I make Mathematica execute the script in an already running local kernel, so that it doesn't go through the overhead of spawning a bunch of new ones every time (which ends up being a rather significant part of the HTTP request time)?

I tried doing this: [Opening a notebook from command line in an existing front end instance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/opening-a-notebook-from-command-line-in-an-existing-front-end-instance)
That's not the answer.

Comment: You could launch an HTTP server and then communicate with it, as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111803/731).